# REPLACE na cláusula IN - MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace

Eu tenho a seguinte query abaixo, sendo que a idéia é pegar o valor da variável @subcategorias e colocar no IN da consulta:

```
set @subcategorias = replace('10, 11, 29, 30, 31', '''', '');

SELECT 
car.NomeCaracteristica,
MAX(catcar.Valor) AS Valor,
catcar.Condicional AS Condicional
FROM 
caracteristica car
    inner join categoriacaracteristica catcar on car.IdCaracteristica =     catcar.IdCaracteristica
WHERE
catcar.IdCategoria IN (@subcategorias) AND
catcar.IdCaracteristica = 19 AND
catcar.Valor is not null 
GROUP BY
car.NomeCaracteristica,
catcar.Condicional;
```

Fazendo dessa forma, não me retorna a quantidade de registros que eu preciso. Deveria retornar dois ao invés de um.

Eu sei disso porque seu eu colocar o valor no IN na mão (catcar.IdCategoria IN ('10, 11, 29, 30, 31')) ele funciona.

Álguem sabe me dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente é problema de sintaxe.

Você disse que se fizer isso "na mão" funciona:

```
catcar.IdCategoria IN ('10, 11, 29, 30, 31')
```

Funciona só se `idcategoria` for exatamente a *string* `10, 11, 29, 30, 31`, afinal o `IN` espera uma lista de ítens separada por vírgula.

Do jeito que fez, `'10, 11, 29, 30, 31'` é um ítem só (o fato de ter vírgulas dentro da *string* não tem relação nenhuma com a lista de ítens que o `IN` espera).

Estes dois exemplos são completamente diferente da linha acima:

```
catcar.IdCategoria IN ( 10, 11, 29, 30, 31 )
```

e

```
catcar.IdCategoria IN ( '10', '11', '29', '30', '31' )
```

Neste caso, são 5 ítens diferentes, e não uma *string* como descrito na pergunta.

Se quer achar dados em uma string separada por vírgulas, a função é outra:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( catcar.IdCategoria, '10,11,29,30,31' )
```

Manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

**Nota:** o que poderia funcionar, no seu caso, é aplicar o seu raciocínio a uma linguagem extra que esteja gerando a *query*, aí se trata de uma situação completamente diferente.

Exemplo em PHP:

```
$lista = '10, 11, 29, 30, 31';
$sql = ' ... resto da query... WHERE catcar.IdCategoria IN ('.$lista.') AND ...';
mysqli_query( sql );
```

Isto já funciona, pois está acontecendo fora da camada SQL. Quando o SQL processar a string, as aspas já nem estariam lá. Aí sim, um `replace` da respectiva linguagem ainda teria eficácia.

Comment: Mas eu cheguei a fazer um replace na variável (set subcategorias = replace('10, 11, 29, 30, 31', '''', '');) que vai no IN e tirando elas, ficaria os 5 itens, mas mesmo assim, não funcionou.
Até dei um SELECT subcategorias pra saber se estava sem as aspas e estava.

Comment: Sim, isso eu li na pergunta. E não tem o mínimo fundamento achar que o replace tenha qualquer relação com o número de ítens. Uma _string_ é uma _string_.

Comment: Blza... compreendido!
Usei o FIND_IN_SET e funcionou.

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @Cmcampos86 Uma observação: se estiver usando alguma linguagem paga gerar/usar as queries, pode usar o IN, mas precisa remover as aspas antes do SQL. Publiquei uma solução para MySQL puro, pq é o que tinha na pergunta. Mas numa linguagem que possa manipular a query (em vez dos valores da query), dá pra fazer o que você tentou (mas fora da camada SQL). O `FIND_IN_SET` faz busca na string, mas não é tão eficiente quanto IN + lista.

Comment: Haaaaa entendi @Bacco!
Seguirei esta dica!

Obrigado!